# ngIf hiding entire parent div

Tags: angular

```
<h1>{{profile.name}}</h1>
    <!-- shows the posts when the user is not logged in -->
    <div class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <p>{{post.title}} - {{post.content}}</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Does not show the posts title or content -->
    <div class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <p>{{post.title}} - {{post.content}}</p>
        <div  *ngIf="owner(post)">
            <button (click)="edit(post)">Edit</button>
            <button  (click)="delete(post)">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<new-post-form *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn() && auth.getUserDetails()._id === id" (postCreated)="addPost($event)"></new-post-form>
```

I am trying to figure out why the second ngFor directive is not showing anything when the user is not logged in.  The posts array is being set in the component successfully (the first ngfor directive works successfully when the user is not logged in).  The second ngfor directive is supposed to show what the first one shows if the user is not logged in or if the id of the user does not match the author property of the post but its hiding everything not just the two buttons.

Here is the relevant component code -

```
profile: Profile;
  posts: Post[];
  id: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');


    this.data.getProfile(this.id)
      .subscribe(profile => {
        this.profile = profile;
      });

    this.data.getPosts(this.id)
        .subscribe(posts => {
        this.posts = posts;
      });
  }

owner(post) : boolean {
    return post.author === this.auth.getUserDetails()._id;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function `owner` probably doesn't work when user is not logged in. Because `this.auth.getUserDetails()` is likely `undefined` or `null`

Try replacing your code with this:

```
owner(post) : boolean {
  return this.auth.getUserDetails() && post.author === this.auth.getUserDetails()._id;
}
```